# Prevent ngRepeat flicker with promise in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, promise

I have a collection of objects, say `Products`, which I can interact with using `$resource`. On an index page, I'd like to either display the collection, or, in the case the collection is empty, display a helpful message. i.e.

#### In Controller

```js
$scope.products = Products.query();
```

#### In Template

```html
<div ng-repeat="product in products">
  ...
</div>

<div class="alert" ng-hide="products.length">
  <p>Oops, no products!</p>
</div>
```

This works fine, provided the user isn't staring at the spot where the `ng-repeat` will occur. If they are, or if there is a delay in the response from the server, they may notice a slight flicker, before the promise is resolved.

Given that, "invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference" (see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)), such a flicker will always in this example. Instead, I find myself writing:

```html
<div class="alert" ng-hide="!products.$resolved || products.length">
  <p>Oops, no products!</p>
</div>
```

Which takes care of the flicker. However, I'm not too keen on letting my view know exactly how the `products` are obtained. Especially if I change this later on. Is there anything cleaner I could do? I'm aware that a fallback for `ng-repeat` is in the works (see [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/5919)), however, just wondering if there's a cleaner solution in the meantime.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the success method to set the object:

```
Products.query(function(data) {
    $scope.products = data;
});
```

Or use the promise:

```
Products.query().$promise.then(function(data) {
   $scope.products = data;
});
```

This way, the object doesn't become empty until you get a response.

Comment: Thanks. Also, the `ng-hide` will need to be changed to something along the lines of `ng-show="products && products.length === 0"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `$promise` out of `$resource` and change displayed information before/after promise is resolved.

Say you have following Products and service to get them.

```
/* products */
[
 { "id":1, "name":"name1" },
 { "id":2, "name":"name2" },
 ...
]
/***/

app.factory('Products', function ($resource) {
  return $resource('products.json'); 
});
```

Then in your controller assign data only after promise is resolved.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, Products) {
  $scope.initialize = function () {
    $scope.products = null;
    Products.query().$promise.then(function (data) {
      $scope.products = data;
    });
  };

  $scope.initialize();
});
```

In your HTML template you can take care of the cases like a) not yet resolved b) resolved  c) resolved but no data

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-show="!products">
    Getting data... please wait
  </div>

  <div ng-show="products && products.length === 0">
    Oh noes!1 :( No products
  </div>

  <div ng-show="products">
    <span  ng-repeat="product in products">
      {{ product | json }} <br>
    </span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <button type="button" ng-click="initialize()">Refresh</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Related plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/Ggzyz9